# php spl_autoload_register help... just not understanding

Tags: php, spl-autoload-register

my class naming convention: class.ClassName.php

my class file naming convention: class.classname.php (hence the strtolower).

the class files are located in the include path: /home/content/XX/XXXXXX/html/projects/include/

```
//autoload.php
<?php
    class Autoload {
        public static function autoloadClasses($className) {
            $className = strtolower($className);
            $file = dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'include/class.' . $className. '.php';
            require_once($file);
        }
    }
    $register = spl_autoload_register('Autoload::autoloadClasses');
?>

//check4.php
<?php
    $company = $s->company;
    $projectName = 'development';
    $items = array('type', 'scope', 'table', 'conditions');
    $things = array('select', '*', 'todos', array('company'=>$company, PROJECT_NAME=>$projectName));
    $combinedArray = array_combine($items, $things);
    $q = new Query($combinedArray);
?>
```

[verified classes exist and are included http://technicheian.com/images/includedClasses.png](http://technicheian.com/images/includedClasses.png)

on every page that makes use of a class (e.g. this one calling Query; located class.query.php:

`05-Nov-2011 20:18:30]PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Query' not found in /home/content/XX/XXXXXX/html/projects/check4.php` on line 9

at the end of class.session.php is `$s = new Session` (noted here to say that the $company variable should not be empty).

I've read pretty much every article, how-to, etc. I can find. What am I missing?

running php 5.2

Comment: Delete the `set_include_path` bit -  you're not using it here. Also, have you checked that your class exists in the file `{AutoloaderClassDir}/include/class.{ClassName}.php` taking uppercase names into consideration?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. updated my code (and post). Usually these types of changes aren't very complicated or difficult to implement. However, I've edited nearly all of my code around the usability of this much-desired feature. Everything I read while researching made this appear to be a trivial implementation ("you just add this snippet of code and you're good"). Autoloader being somewhat of a router, the majority of my application breaks (obviously) without having access to the classes.

Comment: Why do people keep re-inventing the wheel? Take a look at Zend_Loader_Autoloader (http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.loader.autoloader.html)

Comment: @DigitalPrecision: would this mean that I would have to 'port' my entire app to the Zend Framework? Or, can I just utilize that 'wheel'? (Sorry, probably a dumb question)

Comment: Not a dumb question, Zend_Framework can be used as a stand alone vendor lib from which you can build on, without having to use the controller etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

delete the `file_exists` check and look at your error logs.  You will see which file you were trying to require.  I think it may be confusion on what `__FILE__` does (because it is working on the autoload.php file).

**Edit**:  It looks like this

`dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'include/class.'`

should be changed to

`/home/content/XX/XXXXXX/html/projects/include/class.`

There are a number of things for you to check to ensure that autoloading works:

1. For your custom autoloading to be active it must be registered.  So the `spl_autoload_register('Autoload::autoloadClasses')` must be executed.  A good way of doing this is to edit php.ini and set the auto_prepend file to call your autoload file.
2. Your autoload code must then find the correct file with the correct extension (possibly respecting the php include_path priority that you want).

Comment: Yes, good catch. As an alternative that could be left in code if done properly, on failure, log the filename you are trying to open.

Comment: @Paul: thx. updated post to reflect changes. error log outputs same as browser error output:

05-Nov-2011 20:18:30]PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Query' not found in /home/content/XX/XXXXXX/html/projects/check4.php on line 9

at the end of class.session.php is $s = new Session; code on check4.php:

<?php
 $company = $s->company;
 $projectName = 'development';
 $items = array('type', 'scope', 'table', 'conditions');
 $things = array('select', '*', 'todos', array('company'=>$company, PROJECT_NAME=>$projectName));
 $combinedArray = array_combine($items, $things);
$q = new Query($combinedArray);
?>

Comment: @tchnchn The message from the error log does not have 'include' in the pathname.  Also, are you sure your autoloader is being run.  You can check by putting an echo statement in it.

Comment: @Paul: thanks for hangin in with me on this one. I'm obviously not understanding how this works. Autoloader is definitely not running. Put echo statement... nada. And therein lies my knowledge gap. Does this function need 2 b @ the top of each page calling a class/object? i tried that but it said I couldn't redefine it. Also, re: the error msg not having /include/... does the calling file need 2 b in the same directory as the class include? Finally, I've got my autoloader class file located higher in file structure than classes, so... /html/project/autoloader.php.

Comment: @tchnchn no worries, I hope you can get it solved.  I edited in a response to your questions.  Point 1 covers how to put it at the top of each page (using /etc/php.ini)  The calling file, include files and autoloader can be in completely different directories.

Comment: Haven't completely solved it yet but I feel I have enough information now to hunt the solution down. Thanks to all.

Comment: @Paul
Your answer was .. The Answer :) It was all in the 'prepend' statement in php.ini. Thank you!